# Trying to return a random post with Vue 3 composition API and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to wrap my head around the composition api, but apparently need a bit of help.
Loading in all my "Quotes" from a Firebase DB with this

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const getQuotes = () => {
  const quotes = ref([])
  const error = ref(null)

  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await projectFirestore.collection('quotes').get()
      
      quotes.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
        return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      error.value = err.message
      console.log(error.value)
    }
  }

  return { quotes, error, load}
}

export default getQuotes
```

Which works as intended.
But then I try to create a filter so only 1 Quote is shown randomly like this:

```
<template>
  <section class="home">
    <h1 style="color: pink">{{ randomQuote }}</h1>
    <Quote :quote="quote" v-for="quote in quotes" :key="quote.id" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import getQuotes from '@/composables/getQuotes'
import Quote from '@/components/Quote.vue'
import { computed } from '@vue/reactivity'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: { Quote },
  setup() {
    const { quotes, error, load } = getQuotes()
    const randomQuote = computed(() => {
      return quotes.Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
    })

    load()

    return { randomQuote, quotes, error }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my head this should work... anyone who can spot the error and give me a heads up?

Comment: `quotes.Math.floor`

Comment: @EstusFlask meaning?

Comment: You asked about the error, that's it. `quotes.Math` means that you try to access a property named Math on quotes array, which doesn't exist. If your intention is to calculate array index, this is a wrong syntax to do this.

Comment: @EstusFlask Could you please add your comment with the solution as an answer to make it more visible and help the community to find it? Thanks.

Comment: @Vicky I'm not sure this will help anyone else because this looks more like a typo, any way, I posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax means `quotes.Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)` that a property named `Math` on `quotes` array, while it's `Math` global variable that is supposed to be accessed. Since an array doesn't have such property, this will result in error. If the intention is to specify dynamic array index, it cannot be differed from accessing a property.

In order to access an index, bracket notation should be used, likely:

```
quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]
```